# Java static class that extends an abstract class

Tags: java

This might be a really stupid question, but this is the pattern that I'm interested in implementing.

Here's a basic version of the abstract class that I've implemented.

```
public abstract class MyCollection {
   public abstract String baseUrl();

   public void get(ResponseHandler handler) {
      myApi.get(baseUrl(), handler);
   }
}
```

And here's my basic static collection object

```
public class Users extends MyCollection {
   @Override
   String baseUrl() {
      return "/users";
   }
}
```

And here's what I would love to be able to do in one of my controllers

```
Users.get(new ResponseHandler() {
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(Object obj) {
      //store data
   }

   @Override 
   public void onError(Object obj) {
      //tell user
   }
});
```

My problem is that Java isn't letting me access the `get` function inside `MyCollection` abstract class. Is there a way to get this pattern to work? It seems so pretty and clean to me.

Comment: Did you mean to make `Users` extend `MyCollection` rather than `MyModel`? And why does your title talk about a static class, when there's no sign of one in the question? `MyCollection.get` is an *instance* method - but you're trying to call it as if it were a *static* method. It's hard to understand what you're after here...

Comment: you are invoking an instance method as a static method `Users.get()`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot invoke `Users.get()` because of the following reasons:

-- static methods are not inherited, even if your `MyCollection` class would contain a static `get()` method (which it doesn't contain; it contains an instance `get()` method, instead)

-- there is no static `get()` method in your `Users` class.

These two combined should give you a better view on why you cannot make that call.